# Using prefixes in Cellfie

Tags: owl, iri, manchester-syntax

I have a problem with Protege's Cellfie. I'm trying to import something and I wanted to declare prefixes for all the individuals, objectProperty, and its "range". Any ideas?

Currently, the following gives an error, I already tried using IRI <ontologies/linkingOntology#calculatedUsing) but with no luck.

```
Individual: @A* (mm:prefix = "ontologies/SDWOWL#")
Facts: calculatedUsing (mm:prefix = "ontologies/linkingOntology#") @B* (mm:prefix = "ontologies/otherOntology")
```